# Ошибка "IllegalStateException" при использовании фрагмента

Tags: android, kotlin

Всем привет, намучался с Fragment андроид. А проблема вот в чем. Я получаю вот такое исключение:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.kocmuk.swiftkeepass_ultimate2.Activities.EmptyFragment did not create a view.
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3748)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:114)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2457)
        at com.example.kocmuk.swiftkeepass_ultimate2.ListScreen.ListFragment.onCreate(ListFragment.kt:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6758)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6139)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Оно выпадает у меня при рестарте активности, не нашел хорошего ответа в интернет. Похожая ситуация вот с [этим вопросом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105206/illegalstateexception-fragment-did-not-create-a-view-after-orientation-change). Однако правильный ответ так на него и не дан.

Вот моя активность (часть кода вырежу, так как кода там много):

```
class ListFragment : FragmentActivity(),ListInterface.ViewInterFace {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.list_fragment_activity)
        drawFragment(pathItem)

    }
    override fun drawFragment(pathItem:String) {
        val initialFragment: Fragment = ListScreenFragment()
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putString("pathGroup", pathItem)
        args.putString("path",pathDb)
        args.putString("password",passwordDb)
        initialFragment.arguments = args
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)

        fragmentTransaction?.replace(R.id.content_fragment, initialFragment)
        fragmentTransaction?.commit()
    }
}
```

Вот активность Fragment (Тоже сокращена):

```
class ListScreenFragment : android.support.v4.app.Fragment() {
    var pathDb = ""
    var passwordDb = ""
    var pathItem = ""
    var breadCrumpsArray: LinkedList<GroupItem>? = null
    var groupItem: GroupItem? = null
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_activity, container, false)
        return view
    }
}
```

Ну и, наконец, сам fragment:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/content_fragment"    
    android:name="com.example.kocmuk.swiftkeepass_ultimate2.Activities.EmptyFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Вопрос: как починить эту ошибку?

Comment: вы на создании фрагмента хотите передать в него какие-то начальные данные? Это делается не так. По крайней мере, в `java`. Не думаю, что  `kotlin` в этом плане отличается

Comment: @Jarvis_J , Нет, это я там не вырезал до конца, переменные, суть в том, что Fragment рушится в случае, если приложение выгрузилось из ОЗУ, находясь в свернутом состоянии, а потом было сново запущено. Или вы имеете ввиду про Bundle? Так я гуглил, находил именно такое решение

Comment: я про `Bundle`. Правильно делать через `newInstance` (начните вводить во фрагменте, он сам все подскажет) и передавать аргументы туда `MyFragment.newInstance(path,pasword...)`. Хотя может в `kotlin` теперь допускается тупо через `Bundle`

Comment: оно работает, но пишут, что может вызывать ошибки. Я пробовал, не встречал... но, возможно, это ваш счастливый случай)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, проблема в том, как вы вызываете фрагмент. addToBackStack вызываете до замены самого фрагмента.

```
fun replaceFragment(viewId: Int, fragment: Fragment){
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(viewId, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
}
```

Попробуйте такой порядок. И еще небольшое замечение по коду: название активити должно быть: MainActivity, BooksListActivity и т.д. (ListFragment неудачное название).

Comment: К сожалению это не причина, во-первых, эту строку я уже добавил во время поисков решения, во-вторых, вот тут https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments приведено именно такой пример

Comment: Насчет кода я знаю )))) Буду исправлять, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы указываете в разметке имя фрагмента для статического создания, причем фрагмент создаете другой: EmptyFragment а не ListScreenFragment, а потом динамически в него вставляете другой фрагмент, при перевороте экрана не может пересоздаться удаленный EmptyFragment
Вашу проблему должно решить изменение кода разметки:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/content_fragment"   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```